# Paragraph spacings using SpannableStringBuilder in TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

As the question indicates, I am working on a `TextView` which will show formatted text using `SpannableStringBuilder`. It has multiple paragraphs and I would like to know what would be the easiest (or at least the least complicated) way to set spacing between paragraphs using some inbuilt span. Is this possible? Or will I be required to build a custom span class for this?

Answer (score 8):

Implement the `LineHeightSpan` and override `chooseHeight` method as follows

```
@Override
public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end,
        int spanstartv, int v, FontMetricsInt fm) {
    Spanned spanned = (Spanned) text;
    int st = spanned.getSpanStart(this);
    int en = spanned.getSpanEnd(this);
    if (start == st) {
        fm.ascent -= TOP_SPACING;
        fm.top -= TOP_SPACING;
    }
    if (end == en) {
        fm.descent += BOTTOM_SPACING;
        fm.bottom += BOTTOM_SPACING;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `\n` at the end of your each paragraph text.

Comment: If you could provide the implementation of `ILineHeightSpan` for Xamarin, I would fall in love.

Comment: Note: this will also affect a cursor height if you are using this span inside EditText.

Comment: Are TOP_SPACING and BOTTOM_SPACING density independent or not?